# jquery issue to select element

Tags: jquery, html, toggle, show-hide

I have code block as follows... two show/hide two divs. i.e. toggle between the divs.

```
<li class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3">
     <div id="front" class="riddles-border">
        <div class="reddle-question"><p>Question 1</p></div>
        <div class="riddle-ans"><a href="javascipt:void(0)" onclick="openAns(this)">Answer</a></div>
     </div>
     <div id="back" class="riddle-sliding-content">
        <a href="avascipt:void(0)" onclick="closeAns(this)"><span class="toggle-button r-close"></span> </a>
        <div class="r-answer"><p>Answer 1</p>
     </div>
     </div>
 </li>

 <li class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3">
     <div id="front" class="riddles-border">
        <div class="reddle-question"><p>Question 2</p></div>
        <div class="riddle-ans"><a href="javascipt:void(0)" onclick="openAns(this)">Answer</a></div>
     </div>
     <div id="back" class="riddle-sliding-content">
        <a href="avascipt:void(0)" onclick="closeAns(this)"><span class="toggle-button r-close"></span> </a>
        <div class="r-answer"><p>Answer 2</p>
     </div>
     </div>
 </li>
```

Now when the `openAns()` is clicked, I want to fadeout `$('front')` div and fadein `$('back')` div. And, when `closeAns()` is clicked, I want to fadein `$('front')` div and fadeout `$('back')` div. I am not able to get the div from the clicked `<a>` element in jquery. Can anyone help?

Comment: What do you mean that you cannot get the div in jQuery? Why can't you get the divs by id as 'front' and 'back'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to `set class` instead of `id` for  div's  because id should be unique and use  like this

```js
 function openAns(anchor)
{

    $(anchor).parent('div').parent('div').next('div.back:hidden').fadeIn();
    $(anchor).parent('div').parent('div').fadeOut();

}

function closeAns(anchor)
{
   
      $(anchor).parent('div').prev('div.front:hidden').fadeIn();
    $(anchor).parent('div').fadeOut();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3">
     <div id="" class="riddles-border front">
        <div class="reddle-question"><p>Question 1</p></div>
        <div class="riddle-ans"><a href="javascipt:void(0)" onclick="openAns(this)">Answer</a></div>
     </div>
     <div id="" class="riddle-sliding-content back" style="display:none">
        <a href="avascipt:void(0)" onclick="closeAns(this)"><span class="toggle-button r-close"></span>Question </a>
        <div class="r-answer"><p>Answer 1</p>
     </div>
     </div>
 </li>

 <li class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3">
     <div id="" class="riddles-border front">
        <div class="reddle-question"><p>Question 2</p></div>
        <div class="riddle-ans"><a href="javascipt:void(0)" onclick="openAns(this)">Answer</a></div>
     </div>
     <div id="" class="riddle-sliding-content back" style="display:none">
        <a href="avascipt:void(0)" onclick="closeAns(this)"><span class="toggle-button r-close"></span>Question </a>
        <div class="r-answer"><p>Answer 2</p>
     </div>
     </div>
 </li>
```

Comment: i forgot to tell that I have multiple divs like this...so need to toggle particular div, so sending current object in function

Comment: please attach one more div set with your question . so i can work for that @ghetal

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
function openAns(thiss) {   
    thiss.parent().parent().fadeOut();
    thiss.parent().parent().fadeIn();
}

function closeAns(thiss) {
    thiss.parent().parent().fadeIn();
    thiss.parent().parent().fadeOut();
}
```